# Using ZeroMQ or other MQ to send objects

Tags: json, node.js, rabbitmq, zeromq, mqtt

I am wondering how I can send objects via a message queue. My question is two-fold:

(1) are there any message queues like ZeroMQ that support Java objects and JSON out of the box?

(2) are there any message queues that don't require you to serialize/deserialize objects on both ends?

Comment: Please research questions like this first.  A very straightforward Google search turned up a number of options.

Comment: apparently your google search skills are better than mine...kindly share a link

Comment: (2) only embedded MQ will support this features. As soon as the network is involved, the object will be serialized. I only know ZeroMQ as a full MQ. You could look too at [frameworks which implements EIP](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/), eg. for java Camel, Spring Integration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, at the very least MQTT will accept JSON payloads, because we we use that ourselves.

On your second point, its difficult to see how any inter-platform transport can avoid serialisation, as one end does not know the language or endian-ness of the other end.

Comment: I don't think it's so far fetched to send objects without serializing to a standard format like csv, json or xml. Of course objects will have to be serialized to be sent over the network, but I want to know if they can be sent as is.